# Why does this code show the "cannot convert 'double' to 'double*'" error?

Tags: c++

Consider this code:

```
double dist(double x[3], double y[3])
{
    double Sum;
    double distance;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter value of first coordinate";
        cin >> x[i];
        cout << "Enter value of second coordinate";
        cin >> x[i];

        Sum = Sum + pow((x[i] - x[i]), 2.0);
        distance = (int)sqrt(Sum);
    }
        cout << "DISTANCE: " << distance;
    return distance;
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    double x[3]; double y[3];
    cout << "enter number of test case" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        dist(x[i], y[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On the line `dist(x[i], y[i])` it keeps giving the error

> cannot convert 'double' to 'double*' for argument '1' to 'double dist(double*, double*)'

Comment: `Sum = Sum + pow((x[i]-x[i]),2.0);` You are using `x[i]` twice. Is that what you meant?

Comment: `dist` expects an array of three doubles. `x[i]` is just one double value.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Technically, `dist` expects two pointers to `double`s. The `3` is meaningless.

Comment: @T.C. I know. I tried to avoid adding to confusion, which is already present in abundance. Also, it is perhaps correct to say that `dist` expects an array of three doubles as part of its contract, regardless of how well this fact is expressed in its signature.

Comment: `Sum` also needs to be initialized.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you pass an array to a function:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dist(x[i], y[i]);
}
```

You probably thought that you were calling the function `dist` once with an array containing all the values from `x[0..n-1]` (and likewise for `y`). This is not so. Since you are in a loop, you are calling the function for as many times as the loop runs, which in this case is `n` times.

Furthermore, the values you are passing as parameters to the function are elements of type `double`. It is not the array that you thought you were providing.

---

And I know that the error message seems strange. "Where is `double*` coming from?" you may have asked yourself. Well the answer is simple:

**Arrays cannot be passed to function.**

Because of something called "type decay", arrays are converted into pointers to their first element (the base address) when they are used in expressions. The parameter types for `dist` (`dist(double x[3], double y[3]`) are exactly equivalent to `dist(double* x, double* y)`. This means while you were incorrectly trying to pass `double`'s to the function the compiler reported that you couldn't convert them to pointers.

Passing the name of the array will pass a pointer to the first element. This will solve your main issue:

```
dist(x, y);
```

The reason you can still use the subscript operator `x[n]` on a pointer is because the subscript operator is syntactical sugar for `*(x + n)`. That is, a pointer offset by `n` plus a dereference to give you the value at that address.

---

This type decay also entails another problem: since the array is being converted into a pointer, the size information that comes along with its type can't be determined. You can have a function that takes a `double[100]` and pass it an array that holds 1 element because when the array decays to a pointer their types match exactly. There are a few ways around this:

- Make the parameter a reference/pointer to a function
- Use a standard library array class

Now, [a pointer and a reference are two different things,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) but they can still be used to solve this problem. Using a reference to an array is different than actually passing in an array itself. References act as aliases to objects, and they are basically a pointer under the hood with a few exceptions (see the provided link). A reference is good enough for our example however, here is what it looks like:

```
double dist(double (&x)[3], double (&y)[3]);
```

Type decay will not occur here, and you have a guaranteed size because the compiler will report an error if an array of any other size was passed in.

A reference is useful, but it can be off putting for first timers. Fortunately the standard library provides us with an array class `std::array`. No strange syntax is needed and it has a cleaner interface - no pointers!

```
#include <array>
double dist(std::array<double, 3> x, std::array<double, 3> y);

std::array<double, 3> x, y;
dist(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dist` function already loops 3 times.
You probably want to get rid of the loop in `main()`

```
  cin>>n;
  dist(x,y);
  return 0;
```

That way, both x and y are `double*`

just guessing at your intent here though

Answer (score 0):

Just call

```
dist(x, y);
```

As it is, you're passing the double values from the arrays, not the arrays themselves.